# How is this polynomial factorization derived?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

From Kreyszig's Functional Analysis:

> Let $T : H \rightarrow H$ be a bounded self-adjoint linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$ and let $m = \inf _{\|x\| = 1} \langle Tx, x \rangle$ and $M = \sup _{\|x\| = 1} \langle Tx, x \rangle$.  Let $p(\lambda)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and $p(\lambda) \ge 0$ for all $\lambda \in [m,M]$.

Since $p$ has real coefficients, complex zeros must occur in conjugate pairs if they occur at all.  Since $p$ changes sign if $\lambda$ passes through a zero of odd multiplicity and $p(\lambda) \ge 0$ on $[m, M]$, zeros of $p$ in $(m, M)$ must be of even multiplicity.  Hence we can write:

$$p(\lambda) = \alpha \prod _i (\lambda - \beta_i) \prod _k (\gamma_k - \lambda) \prod _l[(\lambda - \mu_l)^2 + v_l^2]$$

where $\beta_j \le m$ and $\gamma_k \ge M$ and the quadratic factors correspond to complex conjugate zeros and to real zeros in $(m,M)$.

---

How is the factored expression for $p(\lambda)$ derived?  I understand how $\beta_i$ and $\gamma_k$ represent the zeros outside of the interval, but how is the third part of the product derived?  I don't understand how the terms explicitly relate to the complex conjugate and real zeros in $(m,M)$.

Answer (score 1):

The irreducible polynomials in $\mathbf R[X]$ are either linear polynomials (whence the first two factors) or quadratic polynomials without reals roots. Completing the square, a monic quadratic polynomial  can take the form:
$$x^2+bx+c=\Bigl(x+\frac b2\Bigr)^2+\frac{4c-b^2}4, $$
and if this polynomial has no real root, $\;4c-b^2>$0, so it has a square root, whace the third factor.

Comment: So he's just letting $\large \mu = -\frac{b}{2}$ and $\large \upsilon^2 = (\frac{4c-b^2}{4})^2$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The exact values in function of $b$ and $c$ are irrelevant here.

Comment: So how does the fact that the zeros within $(m,M)$ are even
imply this factorization of the polynomial? Is there a specific reason or does it seem that the reason for this particular factorization would be because of a step in the proof?